# How to understand the fun buildString(builderAction: (StringBuilder) -> Unit) : String in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

The following code is from https://github.com/gbaldeck/learning-kotlin/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/org/learning/DSLconstruction.kt

I find it hard to understand.

1:  The `fun buildString` only accept one lambda parameter in Section A, why are there two parameters passed in Section B?

2:  What is full code of Section B?
    Such as

```
 val s = buildString { aa : StringBuild -> aa.append("Hello.") } // I don't know whether it's right?
```

3:  What is this `it` in Section B?  Does this `it` represent `StringBuild` ?

**Section A**

```
fun buildString(builderAction: (StringBuilder) -> Unit ) : String {
    val sb = StringBuilder()
    builderAction(sb)
    return sb.toString()
}
```

**Section B**

```
val s = buildString {
    it.append("Hello, ")
    it.append("World!")
}

logError(s)  //The result is Hello, World!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1: The fun buildString only accept one lambda parameter in Section A, why are there two parameters passed in Section B?

There is only 1 parameter passed to that function: specifically, the `builderAction` of type `(StringBuilder) -> Unit`.

So

```
val s = buildString {
    it.append("Hello, ")
    it.append("World!")
}
```

is equivalent to

```
val s: String = buildString(builderAction = { stringBuilder: StringBuilder ->
    stringBuilder.append("Hello, ")
    stringBuilder.append("World!")
    // return Unit
})
```

Meaning `it` is actually the unnamed single argument of `(StringBuilder) -> Unit`, so it's a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `it` is the `StringBuilder`. It is named `it` by default. You can specify the name if you want to.

```
buildString {
     it.append("...")
}
```

is the same as

```
buildString { it ->
    it.append("...")
}
```

or even

```
buildString { myNewString -> 
    myNewString.append("...")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. There is only one parameter being passed in section B, namely, this parameter:

   ```
   {
       it.append("Hello, ")
       it.append("World!")
   }
   ```

   That is *one* lambda expression, not two. The lambda expression has 2 *lines*, but it's still one lambda.
2. If you want to expand the call to `buildString`,

   ```
   val builder = StringBuilder()
   builder.append("Hello, ")
   builder.append("World!")
   val s = builder.toString()
   ```
3. Yes, the `it` refers to the `StringBuilder` `sb` in `buildString`. When the function type has only one parameter, you can refer to the single parameter with `it` in the lambda expression without giving it a name.